# awx-manage inventory_import --inventory-name --overwrite doesn't work

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I want to update an inventory in ansible awx from a flat file. The --overwrite switch is supposed to replace the existing inventory with the new hosts from the flat file. The command is run in awx_task container:

```
awx-manage inventory_import --inventory-name dynamicHosts --source hosts0707 --overwrite
```

Results: the original hosts in the inventory dynamicHosts are not replaced!!
The manual says they should be overwritten

Anyone experienced this and possible solution?